# CSP not detecting smart card minidriver C#

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, smartcard

I am writing a little program for cryptographic purposes using smart card, but I am having problem with my mini-driver. When I start the program I can see the card (popup dialog for choosing smart card appears) but I cant use it becase of the following:

```
A smart card was detected but is not the one required for the current operation. The smart card you are using may be missing required driver software or a required certificate.
```

C# code that I am using is pretty straightforward, and it goes like this:

```
CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(
        1,
        "Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider",
        "my_container"
);
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);
```

Just to note, I have another application (Gemalto minidriver manager) that recognizes this minidriver, so the problem is not there.

Thanks in advance

### UPDATE

In order for CSP to recognize the smart card, you need to tell it to use default key container. Just add next line before creating RSACryptoServiceProvider:

```
csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer;
```

Comment: I don't think this can be answered in the current format without intricate knowledge about the Gemalto software. You may want to contact Gemalto instead.

Comment: I doubt that they will share details about their software, but I'll try

Answer (score 0):

Check out if the minidriver is installed in both 32 and 64 bits mode.
On 64 bits, the minidriver and its configuration (in the calais database) must be set in both 32 and 64 bits mode.

Comment: I resolved this issue, I updated my post for future reference. Thanks anyway